# Spring JpaRepository saveAll. Как при ошибке сохранить 9 записей из 10 при балковом инсерте?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Пытаюсь сохранить в базу данных список объектов с помощью saveAll() метода из JpaRepository, но возникает такой вопрос. Что если на колонку стоит ограничение varchar(2) например. И из 10 объектов, которые я пытаюсь сохранить 1 имеет длину поля 100 символов. Тогда при вызове saveAll() он не сохранит в таблицу ни одной записи.
Можно ли как то сделать так, что бы 9 из 10 записей попали в таблицу, а, например, эта одна вылетела и сохранилась в какой нибудь список, в котором бы хранились записи, которые не получилось сохрнить?

Answer (score 1):

В JpaRepository saveAll() работает в транзакции, поэтому при возникновении исключения транзакция откатывается.

Простое решение - использовать save()

Более сложное - переопределить saveAll() и использовать propagation